# How to search contacts by name and phone number?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am using Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI to search for contacts.

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(searchString));
```

The `searchstring` can be either a number or a name. That works great.
My only problem is that the result does not contain a contact phone number.

I know that I can get it by querying `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`. However, I would like to find a solution that will give me a contact name and phone number with a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone#CONTENT_FILTER_URI) instead of `Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`

Docs say:

> The filter is applied to display names as well as phone numbers.

Try this:

```
Uri filterUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(searchString));
String[] projection = new String[]{ Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(filterUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: It seems this searches in more than just display-name and phones. Is there a way to be more specific of where to search, and also to get where it was found? I also find it impossible to perform this query to be done only on specific accounts and/or groups.